# XML To array in php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

i have to got response in XML . and i want to convert xml data to array using php.
 my XML record.

```
 <soap:Body>
    <CreateContact xmlns="http://www.tigerpawsoftware.com">
     <pram>
       <OfficePhoneNumber>8387909727</OfficePhoneNumber>
       <EmailAddress>asheesh9308@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
      </pram>
    </CreateContact>
  </soap:Body>
```

Target Array as:-

```
array('OfficePhoneNumber' => 8387909727,
      'EmailAddress' => asheesh9308@gmail.com )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online Example: https://3v4l.org/KcJMX, You can optimize your primary array, Just learn from [function.xml-parse-into-struct.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php), I hope you will do it.

Use `xml_parser_create` and `xml_parse_into_struct` to make your desire array.

Using `xml_parse_into_struct` you will got two array, one is indexes and other is values. So you can generate your desire result from those index and values, As you the indexes you call easily make the desire array.

Also look at those `($index, $vals)` arrays.

```
$xml = '<soap:Body>
            <CreateContact xmlns="http://www.tigerpawsoftware.com">
             <pram>
               <OfficePhoneNumber>8387909727</OfficePhoneNumber>
               <EmailAddress>asheesh9308@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
              </pram>
            </CreateContact>
          </soap:Body>';

$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

echo '<pre>';
$out = array("OfficePhoneNumber" => $vals[$index['OFFICEPHONENUMBER'][0]]['value'], "EmailAddress" => $vals[$index['EMAILADDRESS'][0]]['value']);
print_r($out);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [OfficePhoneNumber] => 8387909727
    [EmailAddress] => asheesh9308@gmail.com
)
```

Comment: it's working well thanx.. But this is "Jugar method" Any other Real Logic plz

Comment: "Jugar method" means?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)() function

**PHP**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('MY_XML_CONTENT', "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
var_dump($array);
```

var_dump should output :

```
array(1) {
  ["CreateContact"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["pram"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["OfficePhoneNumber"]=>
      string(10) "8387909727"
      ["EmailAddress"]=>
      string(21) "asheesh9308@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a [EvalIN](https://eval.in/575481)